# Can't round corners of image in the Card widget

Tags: android, flutter

Android Studio 3.6

I has Card widget and container widget inside it. I want to round container's corners.

Snippet:

```
  Widget _createCardViewContainer() {
    return new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [_createBoxShadow()]),
        height: Constants.CARD_VIEW_HEIGHT,
        child: Card(
            color: Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
            ),
            child: new Stack(
                children: [new Image.asset('assets/images/rpm_card.png')])));
  }



 BoxShadow _createBoxShadow() {
    return new BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
        blurRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS,
        // has the effect of softening the shadow
        spreadRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_SPREAD_RADIOUS,
        // has the effect of extending the shadow
        offset: Offset(
          Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_X, // horizontal, move right 10
          Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_Y, // vertical, move down 10
        ));
  }
```

As you can see I use `RoundedRectangleBorder` but it not help.

Here result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoundedRectangleBorder() works only on the Card().

And somehow in flutter the image doesn't get clipped according to shape of the card.

So you'll need to use a Clipper.

In your case wrap the Image.asset() with a ClipRRect() and give it a borderRadius.

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
    child: Image.asset(),),
```

That should work.

Answer (score 4):

Auto clipping was turned off by Flutter for performance reasons. To turn it back on add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge`:

```dart
Card(
  color: Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,  //add this!
  child: new Stack(
    children: [new Image.asset('assets/images/rpm_card.png')]
  )
)
```

You can also use `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` too.